# Django Multiple classes in Model.py

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. I am trying to create a database of babysitters and one of the objects which can have multiple fields is Education. My first Babysitter has 2 qualifications which produces an error an will not display.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Gzi.png)

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from .models import Babysitter, Education, Work, Reference


# Create your views here.
def all_babysitters(request):
    babysitters = Babysitter.objects.all()
    return render(request, "babysitters.html", {"babysitters": babysitters})

def babysitter_profile(request, id):
    """A view that displays the profile page of a registered babysitter"""
    babysitter = get_object_or_404(Babysitter, id=id)
    reference = get_object_or_404(Reference)
    education = get_object_or_404(Education)
    return render(request, "babysitter_profile.html", {'babysitter': babysitter, 'education': education, 'reference': reference} )
```

models.py

```html
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Babysitter(models.Model):
    list_display = ('firstName', 'lastName', 'minderType')
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    minderType = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    eircode = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=280,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName
        
class Education(models.Model):
    babysitter = models.ForeignKey(Babysitter)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fieldOfStudy = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dateFrom = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    dateTo = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    graduated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.school
        
class Work(models.Model):
    babysitter = models.ForeignKey(Babysitter)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dateFrom = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    dateTo = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.work
        
class Reference(models.Model):
    babysitter = models.ForeignKey(Babysitter)
    refFamily = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.refFamily
```

Can somebody help? I am going to pull my hair out. Thanks

Comment: The code you pasted for your view doesn't match what I see in the stack trace in the error message. Specifically, I don't see a line in `babysitter_profile` that reads `education = get_object_or_404(Education)`. Did you paste the actual file contents? Also, your file titles are swapped (you have the view code under models.py, and vice-versa).

Comment: sorry, I just edited the post now. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Chiheb Nexus. I will try your solution although I would like to be able to display 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing enough information into the calls to get a Reference and Education object:

```
babysitter = get_object_or_404(Babysitter, id=id)
reference = get_object_or_404(Reference, babysitter_id=babysitter.id)
education = get_object_or_404(Education, babysitter_id=babysitter.id)
```

The [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) function is a shortcut that calls [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) underneath, and `get()` only ever returns a single object (returning more than one will result in the Exception you are seeing).

If you want to see more than one object, then don't use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut method (I find those "shortcut" methods to be ugly, personally). Instead, change it to something like:

```
education_qs = Education.objects.filter(babysitter_id=babysitter.id)
```

Then loop over that queryset to get the results:

```
for ed in education_qs:
    # Get some data
    school = ed.school
```

You can loop over the queryset in your HTML template, if that's easier.

**Update**: Here's a better answer that shows how to use querysets:

```
def babysitter_profile(request, id):
    """A view that displays the profile page of a registered babysitter"""
    babysitter = get_object_or_404(Babysitter, id=id)
    reference_qs = Reference.objects.filter(babysitter_id=babysitter.id)
    education_qs = Education.objects.filter(babysitter_id=babysitter.id)
    return render(request, "babysitter_profile.html", {
        'babysitter': babysitter,
        'education_qs': education_qs,
        'reference_qs': reference_qs}
    )
```

Then, in your HTML template, you could do something like the following to show the schools the Babysitter has attended (in a bulleted list):

```
<ul>
{% for ed in education_qs %}
    <li>{{ ed.school }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You could do something similar for the Reference data.

Comment: I am sorry to be a pain but it still wont work for me.

Comment: What error do you see? Are you passing the education queryset object (or the data you read from it) to your template through the template context?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a more fully fledged example of usage.

Comment: Thank you so much and to everybody who helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set some `parameters` to get a specific object, rather than get a bunch of objects.

Just do it like the first instance for `get_object_or_404`.

```
reference = get_object_or_404(Reference,id=xx)
education = get_object_or_404(Education,id=yy)
```

Answer (score 1):

[get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) returns just 1 object. Use [get_list_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) if babysitter has "2 qualification" to prevent exception.

```
babysitter = get_object_or_404(Babysitter, id=id)
education = get_list_or_404(Education, id=babysitter.id)
```

To prevent `MultipleObjectReturned` exception.

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://milestone-project-05-minder-finder-pierceoneill.c9users.io/babysitters/babysitter_profile/1/
Raised by: babysitters.views.babysitter_profile
No Education matches the given query.

Comment: Can't see the given query, but know that you still need to `for ed in education:` as @jonahBishop mentioned